# Prevent counter from going minus

Tags: jquery, limit, counter

I have a quantity counter in an ecommerce store which the user can hit to increase or decrease quantities in their cart.  The trouble is, hitting the '-' button allows the quantity to fall below 0, thus being a minus. This could obviously screw up stock levels so I need it to accept 0 as the lowest value only. Totally stuck.

```
        <div class="qty-holder">

    <div class="qty-changer">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="qty_dec"><span>-</span></a>
    </div>

    <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getQty()*1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />

    <div class="qty-changer">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="qty_inc"><span>+</span></a>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(".qty_inc").click(function(){
            jQuery(this).parent().parent().children("input#qty").val((+jQuery(this).parent().parent().children("input#qty").val() + 1) || 0);
        });
    });

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(".qty_dec").click(function(){
            jQuery(this).parent().parent().children("input#qty").val((+jQuery(this).parent().parent().children("input#qty").val() - 1) || 0);
        });
    });

</script>
```

Any ideas would be really appreciative.

Comment: Off topic: *"This could obviously screw up stock levels"*. Everything should be checked server side as well. Otherwise people could just modify the contents client side and still send incorrect data.

Comment: Put the value in a variable, add an if/else case. 
If <= 0 then 0.
ALWAYS check everything server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `.qty_dec` click, first get the value of `(+jQuery(this).parent().parent().children("input#qty").val() - 1)` in a variable.

Then check if value >= 0, display that value else display 0

```
var decValue = (+jQuery(this).parent().parent().children("input#qty").val() - 1)
if decValue >= 0
jQuery(this).parent().parent().children("input#qty").val(decValue);
else
jQuery(this).parent().parent().children("input#qty").val(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Math.max(value, 0)` to get maximum value between two entries

Comment: Though in this case, Phil probably needs `Math.max(value,0)` because he needs the max value within [-1,0].